# Display hide button in listView from a listener

Tags: android, listview, button, listener

I've good an other question for you... ^^

I've got a listView with Button items and a ItemClickListener on this list.

When I click on an item, I want to display the Button of the current item clicked, without re-loading all the listView.

Do you know how can I do it ?

This is my code :

```
public ListView.OnItemClickListener listviewProductsOnItemClickListener =
        new ListView.OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> currentAdapter, View currentView, int position, long id) {           
        Button changeQuantity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changequantity);

        changeQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
};
```

The problem is that the button is ALWAYS displayed on the first item :/

Thanks for your help, and again, sorry for my french english !

Comment: welcome back man..sorry but i can not understand your problem exactly..can you please explain in detail if possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onItemClick will give you currentView from your adapter, you will get your button as give below.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> currentAdapter, View currentView, int position, long id) {           
    Button changeQuantity = (Button) currentView.findViewById(R.id.changequantity);

    changeQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this is to define the click listener in your adapter's `getView()`. this way you'll avoid any confusion..

You may also try using

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> currentAdapter, View currentView, int position, long id) {           
    Button changeQuantity = (Button) currentView.findViewById(R.id.changequantity);

    changeQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```